# how to make content in card view in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

First of all hi everyone ,
this is my first question is there any i make mistake i apologise

here is my question;

i'm using LinearLayoutManager and this is my output

[image]

but i want to this like but i don't know how can i do that ?

[image]

i know this is a card view but i have no idea how can i do that ?

Thank you for now

Comment: please post answer if you found a solution. I am in a similar sort of situation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30583120/550393

Answer (score 1):

The CardView and RecyclerView are contained in version 21 of the v7 support library. See [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) for details on how to include the relevant classes in your app. The RecyclerView is (essentially) a generalization of a ListView.